# Where can I find a list of the Windows EventCodes and their definitions?

Tags: windows, security, logging, windows-event-log

It's fallen to me recently to sift through Windows logs and do some analysis on them.  To start, I'm trying to get familiar with the EventCodes, but I've not had much success finding any comprehensive information on the EventCodes.  Does anybody know of anywhere that might have this kind of information?

I did download a spreadsheet from Microsoft, but it had less than helpful explanation of what each EventCode meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found http://www.eventid.net/ to be a pretty valuable resource when examining event logs.

Comment: Maybe so, but they didn't have any information about the first code I searched: 4624

Comment: +1 for eventid.com.  Always found it has some info on anything I have searched.  Not always as much as I would like. Is this a security event? 4624 is an account logon event.  It is listed here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947226/en-us

Answer (score 1):

Quite honestly I have found that Google is your best resource for this.

Comment: Maybe so, I was hoping to find a unified resource, but I suppose that doesn't exist.